# Drupal 8 Mailchimp Ajax Signup Block

Tags: ajax, drupal, mailchimp, drupal-8

I try to ajaxify the Drupal 8 Mailchimp SignUp Block but I stuck with the AjaxResponse.

This is my Form alter hook:

```
function mailchimp_ajax_form_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id != 'mailchimp_signup_subscribe_block_form') {
    return;
  }
  $form['submit']['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => 'mailchimp_ajax_form_callback',
    'prevent'  => 'click',
    'progress' => array(
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => t('Submitting data...')
    )
  ];

}
```

This is my callback function:

```
function mailchimp_ajax_form_callback(array &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {


  $response = new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse();

  $response->setContent('Response');
  return $response;
}
```

But in Chrome console there is only an error:

```
Uncaught AjaxError: 
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /node?ajax_form=1
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: Response
```

The Signup works, but my question is how can I get the mailchimp response and put it in a valid AjaxResponse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My "working" solution now is:

alter the form block, add an ajax callback function, prevent click and adds some ajax progress visualization.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 *
 * @param \Drupal\mailchimp_signup\Form\MailchimpSignupPageForm $form
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface                  $form_state
 * @param                                                       $form_id
 */
function mailchimp_ajax_form_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id != 'mailchimp_signup_subscribe_block_form') {
    return;
  }
  $form['submit']['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => 'mailchimp_ajax_form_callback',
    'prevent'  => 'click',
    'progress' => array(
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => t('Submitting data...')
    )
  ];

}
```

This is the Ajax Callback:

I create a new `AjaxResponse` Object and an array of the Drupal messages via `drupal_get_messages()`. Then some kind of hack to get the right message.

and add an `ReplaceCommand`Object which replaces the form with the Mailchimp message.

```
function mailchimp_ajax_form_callback(array &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {


  $response = new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse();

  $messages = drupal_get_messages();

  $message = $messages['status'][0];

  if(!$message){
    $message = $messages['warning'][0];
  }

  $response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand('#mailchimp-signup-subscribe-block-form', $message));

  return $response;
}
```

I think there are much more elegant ways to get this. 
I still don't know why the `submitForm` Method of The Mailchimp Form is still invoked...

Answer (score 1):

First, the AjaxResponse object has a [`setData()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor!symfony!http-foundation!JsonResponse.php/function/JsonResponse%3A%3AsetData/8.2.x) method not `setContent()`.

To actually subscribe someone to mailchimp through the Drupal module you can use the [`mailchimp_subscribe()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/mailchimp/tree/mailchimp.module?h=8.x-1.x#n346) function in the main mailchimp module.

Comment: When I change setContent to setData, there is the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token R`. The Subscription works, like I wrote in the Question, but how do I get the Response from the Mailchimp Server in the callback function that I can return it to the Client?

Comment: The `SyntaxError` comes if you doesn't provide an `array` to the `setData` Method. Now I only need the response from the mailchimp_subscribe function which is invokes by the `submitForm` method of the `MailchimpSignupPageForm`

Comment: Yes, setData() expects an array that will be encoded as JSON and passed back to your JavaScript that triggered the request in the first place.  And you should be able to call subscribe function directly.  You can try the handler for the form, but I don't know that'll do what you want in terms or response.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX option is committed to the module, you can find it here: https://www.drupal.org/project/mailchimp/issues/2721249

After applying the patch or using the version that includes it, you'll find a checkbox in the form configuration to enable the AJAX in it.